# Javascript or Query - Convert Associative Array into Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

This is a simple question, not an expert in JS by any means and searched around but couldn't get any existing examples on Stackoverflow to work.

Basically I have a associative array and I need to convert it into an object:

Example:

`var combinedproducts = [["Testing-1","test-1"],["Testing-2","test2"],["Testing-3","test3"]]`

Need it to become this:

```
var products = {
        // 'productid1':'Product Description One',
        'Testing-1':'test-1',
        'Testing-2':'test-2',
        'Testing-3':'test-3'
    };
```

What's the best / simplest way to do this? I can use regular javascript or jquery.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have particular support issues, you can simply use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), assuming "test2" and "test3" are actually array typos rather than intended to be transformed to `test-2` and `test-3` respectively as in your sample output.

Otherwise, you need to apply transformation to them (in that case, either `reduce`, a simple `for` or a `foreach` or even `map` can accomplish that).

Beware that, as mentioned above, Object.entries has not the same support as other solutions. For instance, keep in mind that it WON'T work in IE and Edge in general, [check this link for further compatibility informations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility).

```js
var combinedproducts = [["Testing-1","test-1"],["Testing-2","test2"],["Testing-3","test3"]];

const products = Object.fromEntries(combinedproducts);
console.log(products);
```

Comment: I always forget that exists :)

Comment: Great solution, it's just a shame it's not supported in IE or Edge :(

Comment: @Pointy I usually do as well, not sure why I thought about that this time.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yup, hence my preface :(.

Comment: Thank you for the help this worked! The test text was a typo, no transformation needed.

Noted on the compatibility issues with IE!

Selecting it as the answer as it's the simplest solution to what I was looking for. Simplest read = one line of code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `.reduce()` on your source array:

```
let object = combinedProducts.reduce((o, a) => (
  o[a[0]] = a[1],
  o
), {});
```

For what it's worth, the source array isn't really an "associative array" in any formal sense. JavaScript doesn't have an associative array type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array reduce. Inside the callback function add the first element of the inner array as key and the second element as the value

```js
let data = [
  ["Testing-1", "test-1"],
  ["Testing-2", "test2"],
  ["Testing-3", "test3"]
];

let newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr[0]] = curr[1]
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this method

```js
const c = [["Testing-1","test-1"],["Testing-2","test2"],["Testing-3","test3"]];

obj =  c.reduce((acc, [ key, val ]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: val }), {});
               
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more alternate way doing in one line with `Object.assign` and `map.`

```js
var combinedproducts = [
  ["Testing-1", "test-1"],
  ["Testing-2", "test2"],
  ["Testing-3", "test3"]
];

const obj = Object.assign(
  {},
  ...combinedproducts.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
);

console.log(obj);
```